# ExoPlayer set volume is not working for simple exo player

Tags: java, android, exoplayer

> new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
> @Override
> public void run() {
> if (exoPlayer != null) {
> exoPlayer.setVolume(0); // Mute the player
> }
> }
> 500); // 100 milliseconds delay

i am doing this to mute the exoplayer but its nto working
my exoplayer version is

implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.4.0'

i cant upgrade to latest version because i have to upgrade the whole project which is nto possible at the moment

Comment: Can you checkout their demo app, from the old git repo and checkout that release then you can test it works on that version, see how it's implemented and work your code in the same way?

Answer (score 0):

To control the volume with ExoPlayer, just use this :

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setStreamVolume(exoPlayer.getAudioStreamType(), setVolume, 0);
```

replace setVolume with your desired volume.